# Find $a\in \mathbb R$ so that $\{(a, 1, 1), (1,a,1), (1,1,a)\}$ is a base of $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find $a\in \mathbb R$ so that the list $v=[v_1, v_2, v_3]^t$ is a base of $\mathbb R^3$, where $$v_1 = (a, 1, 1),\ v_2= (1,a,1),\ v_3 = (1,1,a),$$
where $^t$ means transpose.

Any help is highly appreciated, because I don't really know how I could solve this.

Comment: You want the determinant with those vectors as rows or columns to be non-zero

Comment: Thank you! The determinant of the matrix with those vectors as rows and colums is a^3-3*a+2 !=0, and from there we can find that a ∈ R \{-2, 1}. Is this right? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Yes; good job; you must have typed that comment while I was typing an answer (below).  By the way, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n$ vectors in $ \mathbb {R} ^{n}$ are linearly [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Alternative_method_using_determinants) if and only if the determinant of the matrix formed by taking the vectors as its columns is non-zero.

$\begin{vmatrix}a&1&1\\1&a&1\\1&1&a\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}a+2&1&1\\a+2&a&1\\a+2&1&a\end{vmatrix}=(a+2)\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\1&a&1\\1&1&a\end{vmatrix}=(a+2)\begin{vmatrix}1&1&0\\1&a&0\\1&1&a-1\end{vmatrix}$

$=(a+2)(a-1)(a-1) .$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

I have never liked to use matrices or determinants to answer questions about vector spaces.  A "basis" for a vector space of dimension n is a set of vectors that has three properties:

1. The vectors span the space.
2. The vectors are independent.
3. There are n vectors in the set.

Further any two of them are sufficient to prove the third.

This is a set of three vectors so to prove it is a basis for $R^3$ it is sufficient to prove the vectors are independent.  That is, we want to show that if numbers p, q, and r are such that $pv_1+ qv_2+ rv_3= p(a, 1, 1)+ q(1, a, 1)+ r(1, 1, a)= (pa+ q+ r, p+ qa+ r, p+ q+ ra)= (0. 0, 0)$ then p= q= r= 0.

We have pa+ q+ r= 0, p+ qa+ r= 0, and p+ q+ ra= 0..  Subtract the first equation from the second to get (1- a)p+ (a- 1)q= 0.  Divide by 1- a to get p- q= 0 so p= q.  The first two equations become (1+ a)p+ r= 0 so r= -(1+ a)p and the third equation becomes p+ q+ ra= 2p- (1+ a)p= (3+ a)p= 0.  As long as $a\ne -3$ the vectors are independent so a basis for $R^3$.

Comment: Two issues: (1) you divide by $1-a$ without any justification and (2) in the last line you should have $p+q+ra = 2p - (1+a)pa$ making it quadratic in $a$.  [There's an arithmetic mistake too, but in light of the above two, it's moot]

Comment: Thank you! How could I prove that the vectors span the space?